# Can I use an argument in an equation

Tags: java

I have to write a program for school that converts celsius to fahrenheit and vice versa using arguments.
I have the following question:

Let's say the temperature is passed in `arg[1]`, can I apply the conversation equation directly on `arg[1]` like so ?

```
args[1] * 9 / 5 + 32
```

I tried it but I'm having an error about the `*` operator saying "The operator * is undefined for the argument type. I also tried using `"*"` instead.

Here's the unfinished code so far.

**Please do not give me the final code itself as I want to learn instead of being given the answer**

```
public  class Temperature {
    public  static void main(String[] args) {
        int a  = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int b  = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        System.out.println("Veuillez specifier c (celsius) ou f (fahrenheit) suivi de la température. Exemple argc arg32");

        if (args[0].equals ("c"))
        {
            /*convertir en fahrenheit*/
            int temperature = args[1] *9 /5 +32;
        } 
        else if (args[0].equals ("f"))
        {
            /*convertir en celsius*/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a careful look at the type of `args`. Why would performing multiplication on this not make sense?

Comment: Take a look at [exp4j](http://www.objecthunter.net/exp4j/) for evaluating math expressions as strings. I've not used it myself (which is why I'm not posting an answer), but maybe it will be of some use.

Comment: I recommend putting this or some other code of yours up on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using `b`. `args[1]` is still a String, and that is why you are getting that error.

Comment: Ohhhhhh! Make sense. Damn I gave myself a headache try to find what was wrong.

Comment: you can see my little tuto (my answer) and you will find the error yourself user3580294

Comment: IMPORTANT: `b * 9/5 + 32` WILL NOT WORK!  You're working with integers, and `9/5` will be treated as integer division which means it will be 1 instead of 1.8.  Try `b * 9.0 / 5 + 32`, which will  return a `double` instead of an `int`.  If you then want to round, use `Math.round`.

Answer (score 3):

**In general**, yes, you can use elements of arrays directly anywhere you can use that type:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] foo = {2, 4, 6};
    System.out.println(foo[0] * foo[1]); // prints 8
}
```

In your *particular* case, you're getting an error because `args` is a `String[]` ("an array of Strings"), and you can't multiply Strings by integers (in Java, anyway). If you had an array of ints like the above example, it would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to learn things is by giving examples

This is an example of how to use command line arguments to add numbers :

Since these arguments are passed through the command line, they are known as command line arguments. The String arguments passed are stored in the array specified in the main() declaration. args[] is now a three element String array. These elements are accessed in the same way as the elements of a normal array. The following is the complete Add program which is capable of adding any number of integers passed as command line arguments.

```
public class Add {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
           sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("The sum of the arguments passed is " + sum);
    }
}
```

And now you can final your code

Happy coding :)

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this wouldn't help much. OP has shown that he/she knows how to parse integers from the command line.

Comment: While true, your code still doesn't really help OP with his/her problem. OP is experiencing type errors. Not at all what your code is showing.

Comment: so , i have a question , can he/she store float value in int variable ?

Comment: Only if you cast, and in that case you'll lose the decimal portion of the number

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the issue though... While not having integer math mess things up would be nice, it's all for naught if the type errors persist